# lseek() for copying files

Tags: c, file

what i have done : copying the content of file in reverse order.
what i am nt able to do : copy the content in the forward direction .

I made research on the web and I found that `lseek()` has this arguments..

```
lseek(file_descriptor,offset,whence);
```

for reverse reading the logic is straight forward . And my code is as follows :

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd,fd1,count=0;
    char ch='y',buffer;
    if(argc>3)
    {   
        printf("\nSyntax Error!<try> ./cp source_name destination_name\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fd=open(argv[1],O_RDWR);
    if(fd==-1)
    {
        printf("\nCan not open source file .. :(\n");exit(0);
    }

    fd1=open(argv[2],O_RDWR);

    if(fd1=!-1)
    {
         printf("\nDestination file exist , OverWrite (Y/N) :");
         scanf("%s",&ch);
    }

    if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        fd1=creat(argv[2],O_RDWR|0666);
    else
        exit(0);

    while(lseek(fd,count,2)!=-1)
    {
        count--;
        read(fd,&buffer,sizeof(char));
        write(fd1,&buffer,sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

what changes i thought that could be done for copying the file in forward direction .

```
count=0;

lseek(fd,count,0)!=-1


but this is taking the program in infinite loop . need help .
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy in the forward direction you do not need `lseek`.

You need only copy until `read` returns zero:

```
while(read(fd,&buffer,sizeof(char)) > 0)
{
    write(fd1,&buffer,sizeof(char));
}
```

Of course, to do it efficiently you would use a buffer larger than one character, but then you have to be careful how much data you `write` if the last `read` is smaller than the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your backwards copy relies on the `count` becoming negative and seek failing.
This doesn't work for positive offset since [`lseek(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html) allows the offset to be set beyond the end of the file, see the manual page.

Comment: so , can i achieve this .?? forward copy .

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in other answer you don't really need `lseek(2)` for forward copying.